# Access violation upon function termination -- Why is this occurring?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

My program keeps terminating with an access violation error as soon as the the loadInventoryData function terminates:

Unhandled exception at 0x0F9BCCC8 (msvcp110d.dll) in CIS2252 Programming Project.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x007DD314.

The call stack:

```
msvcp110d.dll!std::_Container_base12::_Orphan_all() Line 216    C++
CIS2252 Programming Project.exe!std::_String_alloc<0,std::_String_base_types<char,std::allocator<char> > >::_Free_proxy() Line 680  C++
CIS2252 Programming Project.exe!std::_String_alloc<0,std::_String_base_types<char,std::allocator<char> > >::~_String_alloc<0,std::_String_base_types<char,std::allocator<char> > >() Line 656   C++
CIS2252 Programming Project.exe!std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >() Line 965   C++
CIS2252 Programming Project.exe!loadInventoryData(std::vector<InventoryItem,std::allocator<InventoryItem> > & invMast) Line 220 C++
CIS2252 Programming Project.exe!main() Line 45  C++
CIS2252 Programming Project.exe!__tmainCRTStartup() Line 536    C
CIS2252 Programming Project.exe!mainCRTStartup() Line 377   C
```

The portion of code it's terminating in is:

```
void loadInventoryData(vector<InventoryItem> &invMast)
{
    // Loads invmast.dat or creates one if none exists
    fstream invFile;
    invFile.open("invmast.dat", ios::in | ios::binary);
    if (!invFile)
    {
        cerr << "WARNING: Unable to open file invmast.dat, no inventory records loaded!" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "File invmast.dat opened successfully." << endl;

        string itemName;
        int itemQuantity;
        double itemPrice;

        while (invFile && !invFile.eof())
        {
            invFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&itemName), sizeof(itemName));
            invFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&itemQuantity), sizeof(itemQuantity));
            invFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&itemPrice), sizeof(itemPrice));
            invMast.emplace_back(itemName, itemQuantity, itemPrice); // Create element using constructor with data loaded into invLoader
        }

    }
}
```

In my Main, immediately prior to the function call, these are my vector declarations:

```
vector <InventoryItem> invMast;
vector <Customer> custMast;
vector <CustRequest> custRequest;
```

I am at a complete loss... I would be grateful for anything anyone can do to help determine the cause.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Professional.

Edit:

Thanks everyone for all your help.

I found an article that has a pretty good overview of working with strings in binary files:
http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/DzywvCM9/

Comment: Forgot to mention, the call is immediately after the vector declarations:  loadInventoryData(invMast);

Comment: `reinterpret_cast<char*>` on a pointer to an `std::string` looks really suspicious to me. Try using an actual `char*` buffer, then copying it to a `std::string` and see if that fixes the issue? I suspect you're overwriting the `string`'s pointer to a buffer or something similar, and then it tries to free the junk data you wrote there in the destructor.

Comment: Files are streams of bytes, not streams of objects. Your use of `reinterpret_cast` and `sizeof` is totally broken. You get pointers to objects and sizes of objects and then pretend that that's what you need to serialize objects to a stream of bytes. It is not. Serialization to and from a stream of bytes requires serialization and deserialization code, which you haven't written.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I should mention that this method of reading/writing from binary files is from a book:  C++ How to Program Ninth Edition, and is what we were taught in class.  So I don't know the 'correct' method.  It would be helpful if you could post an example of the 'correct' method, as this would be a useful frame of reference, rather than "your code is bad."

Comment: @Irongrave The correct method is as follows: 1) Devise a file format, define it at the byte level. 2) Write code to convert from whatever internal format your platform uses to that file format. 3) Write code to convert from your file format to whatever internal format your platform uses. (Or punch "serialization" into your favorite search engine.) This kind of use of `reinterpret_cast` is just broken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `string` incorrectly. In this line:

```
invFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&itemName), sizeof(itemName));
```

both reinterpreting `itemName` and using `sizeof` on it are wrong. You cant use the type `string` like a `char` array. This should work out:

```
itemName.reserve(1024);  // or some other size
invFile.read(itemName.c_str(), itemName.capacity());
```

The method `reserve()` allocates a chunk of memory for you to write on, `c_str()` gets you a C style pointer to the string, and `capacity()` gives you the size of the memory you just reserved.

Not sure this is the best solution though, you might want a `char` array instead.

Comment: Why not skip all of that and use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I agree, that is probably the best solution, but I wanted to show what the error is with a small change.

Comment: _"but we cant be sure to what invFile.read() does"_ - Really? Guess my copy of the C++ Standard is wrong  because it tells me exactly what [`read`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) does.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious, crap! I didn't see it's type, I just assumed it was a custom class.

Comment: Can I use std::getline on a binary file, in between two fstream.reads?

Comment: @Irongrave no you can't, `std::getline` is meant for text. And so is `string`.

Comment: Understood... thanks... so in that case, what's the best way to write a string out to a binary file, and read text in that I can then dump into a string to pass to a class constructor?

Comment: @Irongrave, is it a text string in a file with other non-text contents? If so, then using `read()`, but with an C style `char` buffer and then looking for some kind of delimiter to terminate would the way to go (`getline()` also supports delimiters, but you shouldn't use it in binary files). If it is an all text file, then `getline()` is better.

Comment: @Nick It's a text string in a binary file, along with an int and a double

Comment: @Irongrave in that case, reading blocks with `read()` like explained above is the best call.

Answer (score 1):

This line looks wrong

```
invFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&itemName), sizeof(itemName));
```

sizeof(itemName) used that way don't return the capacity of the string, also the stack trace is complaining about string allocation